# XCode 5: How to build Debug configuration only

Tags: xcode, xcode5

It seems that XCode always builds both Debug anв Release configurations (see screenshot attached). I can't untoggle "Profile" option. I need to build Debug version only in 95% of my time. How can I save time by not building Release version every time I press "Build"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, XCode practically always build for Debug, in Release XCode build only when you select from menu Archive or to Profile (shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and you see this because when selected  you see XCode build your project.

Answer (score 0):

The tab you selected just shows the target(s) (MagicCards1 here) that will be built for each action (Run, Profile, Archive...).

Only one build will be made with the appropriate build configuration (Debug, Release, ...) for any given action: your screenshot shows that the 'Debug' configuration will be used to build your target when you run your project, leading me to think that Xcode already does what you're expecting (*and* that it'll only compile the source files that changed since the last build).

You can try to compare Debug and Release builds made from scratch by cleaning (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and building (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) with different build configurations in the scheme's Run settings.

You should also check if **'Build Active Architecture Only'** is set to **Yes** and if **'Analyze during Build'** is set to **No** in your Build Settings:
[image: Analyze during Build screenshot]

You may also want to watch this WWDC 2013 video: Xcode Core Concepts 401. Schemes are covered around the 44'-mark.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?include=401#401

Comment: After Clean (Shift+Cmd+K):
when I press Cmd+К XCode builds 377 files
when I press Cmd+B XCode builds 754 files, which is exactly 2 times more
Why?

Comment: @deko Sorry but Cmd+K stands for which action? (I mean the one with 377 files?) Anyway, in Release mode Xcode always builds exactly twice the number of source files built in Debug on my setup... Also, are you sure you don't have Analysis configured to run after each build? ("Analyze during Build" in the build settings)

Comment: @neural5form Of course I meant "Clean", i.e. "Shift+Cmd+K".
I've got "Enable Performance Analysis" set to "iOS 6 or later" in Run Scheme. I wonder what it means...

Comment: @deko I have this setting set the same way (which I think is for allowing Instruments/Gauges to run performance analysis on the target) so that should not be the cause. Could you check if "Analyze during Build" is set to No in your Build Settings? (see edit)

Comment: @neural5form Thank you for the screen. "Analyse During Build" is set to "No".

Comment: @deko I've managed to solve this problem recently by setting 'Build Active Architecture Only' to Yes in the Build Settings of the project. Tell me if this solves it for you too and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @deko I edited the answer accordingly. Please accept if it works for you too.